# SwiftUI : How I can hide the navigationBar when the keyboard is shown

Tags: swiftui, navigationbar, navigationview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmRu1.jpg)

Please check attached image file, that is situation of mine.

I tried to make this view, but when the keyboard is shown. The main view and navigationBar is mixed.

I hope to hide the navigationBar when I touched the textfield and keyboard is shown.

How I treat that? Thank you all

This is source code below.

```
import SwiftUI

struct FlashCardView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var itemModel : ItemModel

var item : Item

@State var isGeneral : Bool = true
@State var inputAnswer : String = ""
@State var showAlert : Bool = false
@State var isAnswer : Bool = false

@State var randomWord : (String, String) = ("", "")

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        
        HStack {
            if let group = item.group {
                Text("Game with ' \(group) '")
                    .font(.title3.bold())
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .padding()
                    .background(
                        Color.yellow
                            .frame(height : 4)
                            .offset(y : 24)
                    )
            }
            
        }
        
        HStack {
            
            Button(action:  {
                isGeneral = true
                makeNewCard()
            }, label: {
                Text(isGeneral ? "General " : "General")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(isGeneral ? .white : .black)
                    .frame(width : 140, height : 50)
                    .background(isGeneral ? .blue : .gray)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding()
                    
            })
            .shadow(color: .gray.opacity(0.5), radius: 3, x: 3, y: 3)
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action:  {
                isGeneral = false
                makeNewCard()

            }, label: {
                Text(!isGeneral ? "Favorite " : "Favorite")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(!isGeneral ? .white : .black)
                    .frame(width : 140, height : 50)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .background(!isGeneral ? .blue : .gray)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding()
                   
            })
            .disabled(item.children.filter({$0.isFavorite}).isEmpty)
            .shadow(color: .gray.opacity(0.5), radius: 3, x: 3, y: 3)
        }
        
        Text(randomWord.0)
            .font(.title2.bold())
                .frame(maxWidth : .infinity)
                .frame(height : UIScreen.main.bounds.height*0.33)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .shadow(color: .gray.opacity(0.4), radius: 3, x: 3, y: 3)
                .padding()
        
        TextField("What is the answer?", text: $inputAnswer)
            .frame(maxWidth : .infinity)
            .frame(height : 60)
            .font(.body)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .autocapitalization(.none)
            .submitLabel(.done)
            .onSubmit {
                if randomWord.1 == inputAnswer {
                    self.showAlert.toggle()
                    self.isAnswer = true
                    self.inputAnswer = ""
                } else {
                    self.showAlert.toggle()
                    self.isAnswer = false
                    self.inputAnswer = ""
                }
            }
        Divider()
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .padding(.vertical, -10)

        
        Button(action:  {
            if randomWord.1 == inputAnswer {
                self.showAlert.toggle()
                self.isAnswer = true
                self.inputAnswer = ""
            } else {
                self.showAlert.toggle()
                self.isAnswer = false
                self.inputAnswer = ""
            }
        }, label: {
            Label("Check", systemImage: "checkmark.rectangle.fill")
                
                .frame(maxWidth : .infinity)
                .frame(height : 60)
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .background(Color.green)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .shadow(color: .gray.opacity(0.4), radius: 3, x: 3, y: 3)
                .padding()
        })
        .alert(isPresented : $showAlert) {
            Alert(title: Text(isAnswer ? "Nice! that is answer!" : "Sorry, It was not answer.."), message: Text(isAnswer ? "You got an answer! Cool! " : "It's OK!, Keep studying! "), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")) {
                makeNewCard()
            })
            
        }
        .disabled(inputAnswer.count == 0)
        
    } // vst
    .padding()
    .onAppear {
        makeNewCard()
    }
   
    .navigationTitle("Flashcard Game ")
}
}

extension FlashCardView {

func makeNewCard() {
    if isGeneral == true {
        randomWord = itemModel.makeRandomChildren(item: item)
    } else {
        randomWord = itemModel.makeRandomFavoriteChildren(item: item)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you can wrap everything in a `ScrollView`

Answer (score 1):

Add onEditingChanged to the keyboard and add a conditional to the navBar.
If the navBar doesn't hide when the user answers the question, add another toggle to onCommit.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var inputAnswer: String = ""
    @State var isTyping: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text("Hide navbar when user interacts with the textField")
                    .padding()
                TextField("What is the answer?", text: $inputAnswer, onEditingChanged: {
                    self.isTyping = $0 // <= Toggle boolean if user interacts with the textField
                })
                    .keyboardType(.default)
                    
            }
            .navigationTitle("Home")
            .navigationBarHidden(isTyping ? true : false) // <= hide on the condition of the boolean
        }
       
    }
}
```

[image]